# Exit a PowerShell function but continue the script

Tags: function, powershell, exit

This might seem like a very very stupid question, but I can't really figure it out. I'm trying to have the function stop when it finds its first hit (match) and then continue with the rest of the script.

**Code:**

```
Function Get-Foo {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param ()

    1..6 | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Verbose $_
        if ($_ -eq 3) {
            Write-Output 'We found it'

            # break : Stops the execution of the function but doesn't execute the rest of the script
            # exit : Same as break
            # continue : Same as break
            # return : Executes the complete loop and the rest of the script
        }
        elseif ($_ -eq 5) {
            Write-Output 'We found it'
        }
    }
}

Get-Foo -Verbose

Write-Output 'The script continues here'
```

**Desired result:**

```
VERBOSE: 1
VERBOSE: 2
VERBOSE: 3
We found it
The script continues here
```

I've tried using `break`, `exit`, `continue` and `return` but  none of these get me the desired result. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It asks how to exit a function, not how to exit a loop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As was mentioned, `Foreach-object` is a function of its own. Use regular `foreach`

```
Function Get-Foo {
[CmdLetBinding()]
Param ()

$a = 1..6 
foreach($b in $a)
{
    Write-Verbose $b
    if ($b -eq 3) {
        Write-Output 'We found it'
        break
    }
    elseif ($b -eq 5) {
        Write-Output 'We found it'
    }
  }
}

Get-Foo -Verbose

Write-Output 'The script continues here'
```

Answer (score 3):

The scriptblock you are passing to `ForEach-Object` is a function in its own right. A `return` in that script block just returns from the current iteration of the scriptblock.

You'll need a flag to tell future iterations to return immediately. Something like:

```
$done = $false;
1..6 | ForEach-Object {
  if ($done) { return; }

  if (condition) {
    # We're done!
    $done = $true;
  }
}
```

Rather than this, you may be better using a `Where-Object` to filter the pipeline objects to only those that you need to process.

Comment: I'm trying out your example, but I can't get it to work. Can you use mine and adapt so I can see the result? Whatever I do it's still iterating over the other numbers in the `Verbose` stream